# sum of 2 elements in an array groupBy multiple values

Tags: arrays, scala, collections

`case class test(primary : String, secondary : Array[String], count : Int)`

Given array a1:

```
a1: Array[test] = Array(test(Speed,Array(VR,ABC),5), test(Speed,Array.Empty[String],2), test(Speed,Array(Another,VR),3), test(Speed,Array(Another),3))
```

Given array a2:

```
a2: Array[test] = Array(test(Speed,Array(VR,ABC),6), test(Speed,Array.Empty[String],5), test(Speed,Array(Another),2), test(Speed,Array(SomethingElse),2))
```

I need to sum the counts and have it in `new Array[test]` grouped by primary and secondary values. How can I do it? Here count is the total combination of primary & secondary group. These 2 Arrays are statistics generated from 2 Input data. My task here is to aggregate the statistics.

The result should be:

```
a3: Array[test] = Array(test(Speed,Array(VR,ABC),11), test(Speed,Array.Empty[String],7),test(Speed,Array(Another),5),test(Speed,Array(Another,VR),3),test(Speed,Array(SomethingElse),2))
```

Comment: maybe try to use zip and map with accessing the count property of the case class?

Comment: You may Sum two arrays, group in by primary and secondary, your key should be a tuple, then reduce values summing count, and return all reduced values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require that first array contains the same number of elements with the same order of primary/secondary pairs (like you example) you could also do something like that:

```
val a3: Array[test] =
    a1.zip(a2)
      .map {
      case (test1, test2)
        if test1.primary == test2.primary &&
          test1.secondary == test2.secondary
      => test(test1.primary, test2.secondary, test1.count + test2.count))
      case _ => throw IllegalStateException
    }
```

If not, you would probably concatenate both list s and than group by primary/secondary key like Okrm suggested:

```
val a3: Array[test] =
  (a1 ++ a2)
    .groupBy(test => (test.primary, test.secondary))
    .mapValues(_.map(_.count).sum)
    .map { case ((primary, secondary), count) => test(primary, secondary, count) }
    .toArray
```

For given example result should be the same (beside order):

```
a3: Array[test] = Array(test(Speed,Another,5), test(Speed,VR,11), test(Speed,,7))
```

Comment: If Secondary value is not a String but an Array of String, how should I modify?

Comment: Could you be more precise? Do you mean secondary could be [VR, Another]? and what count in such case means? You need probably provide what is given input and what do you expect.

Comment: count in such case means combination of primary and sec group together.

Comment: Could you give me example with expected result, I might help but I still do not know what you want to achieve (maybe in different subject).

Comment: I have just updated my question. Please have a look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just change definition of test as: `case class test(primary: String, secondary: List[String], count: Int)` the second would work easily, but if are not allow to change this definition, solution need to be slightly improved: `val a3: Array[test] =
  (a1 ++ a2)
    .groupBy(test => (test.primary, test.secondary.toList))
    .mapValues(_.map(_.count).sum)
    .map { case ((primary, secondary), count) => test(primary, secondary.toArray, count) }
    .toArray`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
val a3: Array[test] =
  (a1 ++ a2)
    .groupBy(test => (test.primary, test.secondary))
    .mapValues(_.map(_.count).sum)
    .map { case ((primary, secondary), count) => test(primary, secondary, count) }
    .toArray
```

The result of that is:

```
a3: Array[test] = Array(test(Speed,Another,5), test(Speed,VR,11), test(Speed,,7))
```

Comment: you need to use `toArray` to give the output as `Array[test]`.

Comment: If Secondary value is not a String but an Array of String, how should I modify?